# SSAS MDX Product where clause for Average Transaction Value

Tags: where-clause, ssas, mdx

I have the below code which calculates the average transaction value.

CASE
WHEN    IsEmpty([Measures].[Transaction Count]) OR IsEmpty([Measures].[Gross Sales]) THEN 0
ELSE    [Measures].[Gross Sales]/[Measures].[Transaction Count]
END

I need to apply a where clause to this so it only selects certain products...

EAT1, EAT2 and EAT3.

I'm really not sure how best to do this.